# @angular-material-components/datetime-picker is improperly formatted in angular 16

Tags: angular, dependencies, datetimepicker

I could be wrong but it looks like the datetime-picker from angular does not work with angular 16, even though it claims it does. I took the demo from the NPM page for the package, updated the package.json, and then all of the styling of the picker broke. This was the case when I tried to upgrade my own application too. Does anyone know if there is a new dependency that is not mentioned anywhere or a change to the way it's used or something?

Here is the Stackblitz, just make sure to press the update dependencies button to have it load in the angular 16 ones. Press the calendar to see the broken formatting.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-ngx-mat-datetime-picker-vrtdak?file=package.json

Comment: What do you mean by 'broken formatting'?

Comment: The problem is your theming in your css file.  Take a look at the @angular/material theming guide and setup theming.  https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: @manneJan89 By broken formatting I meant that when you click the calendar icon to enter in a date, dates don't highlight blue, theres no background, theres no highlight on the popup window, essentially none of the css is applied.
If you click the calendar, then update dependencies and click the calendar again it will be pretty apparent what happened wasn't right

Comment: The theming shouldn't be the issue either, it worked in Angular 15, and as far as I know there were no breaking theme changes since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in Angular 16.2.1, when I downgraded to Angular 16.1.1 it worked. Not sure why but that is for someone else to figure out sometime I guess. If you are using the datetime-picker just downgrade.